# what is the point of using ternary operators instead of IF THEN?

Tags: c#

why make things more complex? why do this:

```
txtNumerator.Text = 
     txtNumerator.Text == "" ? "0" : txtNumerator.Text;
```

instead of this:

```
if txtNumerator.Text="" {txtNumerator.Text="0";}
```

Comment: I think you'll like the ?? operator.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to pass either zero or txtNumerator.Text to a method M.  How would you do that?

You could say:

```
string argument;
if (txtNumerator.Text == "")
{
    argument = "0";
}
else
{
    argument = txtNumerator.Text;
}
M(argument);
```

Or you could say

```
M(txtNumerator.Text == "" ? "0" : txtNumerator.Text);
```

The latter is shorter and easier to read.

The larger point here is that *statements* are useful for their *side effects* and *expressions* are useful for their *values*. If what you want to do is control which of two side effects happens, then use an "if" statement. If what you want to do is control which value gets chosen from two possibilities, then consider using a conditional expression.

UPDATE:

Jenny asks why not just do this?

```
if (txtNumerator.Text == "")
{
    M("0");
}
else
{
    M(txtNumerator.Text);
}
```

That's fine if there's just one condition to check. But what if there are, say, four? Now there are sixteen possibilities and writing the "if" statement for it gets messy to say the least:

```
if (text1.Text == "")
{
    if (text2.Text == "")
    {
        if (text3.Text == "")
        {
            if (text4.Text == "")
            {
                M("1", "2", "3", "4");
            }
            else
            {
                M("1", "2", "3", text4.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (text4.Text == "")
            {
                M("1", "2", text3.Text, "4");
            }
            else
            {
                M("1", "2", text3.Text, text4.Text);
            }
        }
        ... about fifty more lines of this.
```

Instead, you can just say:

```
M(Text1.Text == "" ? "1" : Text1.Text,
  Text2.Text == "" ? "2" : Text2.Text,
  Text3.Text == "" ? "3" : Text3.Text,
  Text4.Text == "" ? "4" : Text4.Text);
```

Comment: if textbox="" then pass ONE, else pass TWO

Comment: @jenny: OK, now suppose there were three more arguments to M, each of which *also* had a conditional value. That's sixteen possibilities. Would you have sixteen different calls to M?

Comment: @eric please give an example of 3 conditions

Comment: The * [conditional operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/18/whats-the-difference-between-ternary-and-tertiary.aspx) * is also useful when you want to invoke a base class constructor during the initialization of a derived type and you need to pass values that are computed from parameters: `class Foo : Bar { Foo( string txt ) : base( txt == "" ? "0" : txt ) }` - for instance. You could also write static members to do so, but it's far more convenient using `?:` in such cases.

Comment: @LBushkin makes a good point. There are many contexts in C# in which a *statement* is illegal but an *expression* is legal. In some of those contexts you'd like to be able to express the notion of making a choice, but the "if" statement is not available because it is a statement.

Comment: @Eric: Isn't there a pretty significant difference in lambda expressions as well (as in, can't build an expression tree for the `if`/`else` because that's multiple statements)?

Comment: @Ben: Correct; C# does not allow statements in lambdas that are converted to expression trees. We now have an expression tree library that includes statements, so in theory we could do so. It just has not been a priority because building "statement lambda" expression trees does not enable any new LINQ scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

It's one expression, so you can use the result directly in an assignment or a function call without having to duplicate the context in which you're using it.  That makes a lot of usage scenarios significantly cleaner to write and read.  For example:

```
int abs = (x >= 0) ? x : -x;
```

versus

```
int abs;
if (x >= 0)
    abs = x;
else
    abs = -x;
```

Comment: This, to me, is kind of a key point.   You can make subjective arguments about which approach is more aesthetically appealling and a lot will depend on the situation, but having the abilitiy to short circuit a separate declaration statement and assignment statement(s) is significant.   Ultimately, the ternary operation plays a different role than the 'if' one does, because 'if' is useful for creating separate code branches, whereas '?' is useful for obtaining a particular value.

Answer (score 2):

There are many standards guides that say not to use the ternary operator.  However you could agre that all language feature are unnecessary except for goto and if.  I use it when having a multitude of if then elses.

Answer (score 2):

It makes the code more readable in some people opinion, a lot of constructs in the language are syntactic sugar (think about do..while, while..do, and for(..)) and in the end of the day you choose whatever works for you (and your team).

I for example think that the above code should be implemented with an extension method:

```
txtNumerator.SetDefault("0");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the if-then construct, you end up with two assignments to the same variable, in two separate blocks. The ternary form has only one assignment. So there is no need to look at a second block to verify to yourself what both blocks are performing an assignment to the same variable. In that respect I think the ternary form reads better.

On the other hand if C# worked like Ruby and if was an expression, then you could do without the ternary operator and use if-else in that case:

```
txtNumerator.Text = if (txtNumerator.Text == "" ) "0"; else (txtNumerator.Text);
```

which I would prefer because then the different syntax of ?: could be dropped.